# Reacting to the emoji only once - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am developing this bot, and I want the user to be able to react only once in the emoji, and if he reacts other times the command does not work. Can someone help me?

```
let messagereturn = await message.channel.send(embed);

await messagereturn.react('');

const reactions = [''];

const filter = (reaction, user) => reactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === User.id;
const collector = messagereturn.createReactionCollector(filter)

collector.on('collect', async emoji => {
    switch(emoji._emoji.name) {
        case(''):

        const embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#00ff00')
        .setDescription(`${User} **deu um tapa em** ${message.author}`)
        .setImage(rand)

        await message.channel.send(embed1)
    }
})
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are 2 separate languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createReactionCollector` method has an optional `options` object, and it allows you to set the max reactions to collect, which in your case is 1.

example:

```
const collector = messagereturn.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 1 })
```